# Problem with sending email with nodemailer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, nodemailer

There is some error when I want to send email via React website or postman. On the website it shows **Cannot POST /contact**.

here is index.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const port  = process.env.PORT || 5000

const EmailSender = require('./SendEmail.js')

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "25mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "25mb", extended: true}));
 app.use((req, res, next) => {
     res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Nothing important')
})


//send api
app.post('/send', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { user_email, messageSubject, message } = req.body
        EmailSender({user_email, messageSubject, message})
        res.json({msg: "Your message has been sent successfully"})
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({msg: "Error..."})
    }
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is now running at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

here is SendEmail.js file:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const dotenv = require("dotenv")

const Email = (options) => {
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:'gmail', //maybe hotmail instead
        auth: {
            user: process.env.USER, //user or email
            pass: process.env.PASSWORD//password
        },
    })
    transporter.sendMail(options, (err, info) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
            return err;
        }
    })
}

const EmailSender = ({user_email, messageSubject, message}) => {
    const options = {
        from: user_email,
        to: process.env.USER,
        subject: messageSubject,
        message: message,
    }

    Email(options)
}
```

and here is my form:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function ContactUs() {

  const [user_email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [messageSubject, setSubject] = React.useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = React.useState(""); 

  function sendEmail() {
    if(user_email && messageSubject && message) {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/send", {
          user_email: user_email,
          subject: messageSubject,
          message: message,
        })
          .then(() => alert("Email has been sent succesfuly"))
          .catch(() => alert("Something went wrong..."))
      return;
    }
  }

  return (
      <p className='title' id='Title' style={{display: show ? 'block' : 'none'}}>Contact Us</p>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type={'email'} id='emailInput' onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} name='email' placeholder='email' required/>
            <input type={'text'} id='subject' onChange={(e) => setSubject(e.target.value)} name='subject' placeholder='subject' required/>
            <textarea type={'text'} id='message' onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} name='message' placeholder='write a message...' required/>
            <button className='submit' type='submit' onClick={() => sendEmail()}>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I tried to change some variables. I also searched on the internet but nothing helped.

I tried to do `error.reason`, but it showed "undefined".

Comment: Sending email through Gmail via nodemailer has not worked for a while thanks to the security measures put in place by Google themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I needed to generate a special password just for using this one with gmail since gmail has enhanced security to mitigate the risk of hacking your gmail by unauthorized person. You can generate this password in your account manager.